# In Loopback 4, how to avoid update of few fields

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

In loopback framework, is there a way to avoid updates for few fields

Below code allows updates for all fields that is passed in the API request body.

```
async updateById(
    @param.path.number('id') id: number,
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Todo, {partial: true}),
        },
      },
    })
    todo: Todo,
  ): Promise<void> {
    await this.todoRepository.updateById(id, todo);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand from your question, you want to update some part of the object in the database.

`this.repo.updateById(id,objectYouWantToUpdate)`

This is going to work perfectly, just send the data you want to update and not the whole object.

Comment: No, I want to restrict update of few fields in the API

Comment: `schema: getModelSchemaRef(Todo, {partial: true, exclude: ['title']}),` this worked for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`exclude` key can help

`schema: getModelSchemaRef(Todo, {partial: true, exclude: ['title']})`